# Exception Handling for local error recovery

Tags: c++, exception

Is it a bad idea using exception Handling for local error recovery in c++, if yes why?

Comment: For example...? Some reference for somebody saying it's a bad idea?

Comment: its a bad idea to consider something as "bad idea" without rationale. Why do you think it would be bad ?

Comment: please include an example. Exceptions are not "local" by nature. They are thrown in one place and catched elsewhere. You could write something along the line of `try { throw 1; } catch (...) {}` which comest clostest to a "bad idea" among what I can imagine